# How to clear cache of IFrame using c# Code in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iframe, .net-3.5

In my asp.net (Runtime Version 3.5) there is a requirement of displaying Pdf in the middle of the page along with other content.

So in such case I found the solution. for this I used Iframe . But we have to display the pdf on linbutton_click event.

HTML part

```
<div id='Pdfviewer'>
    <iframe id="ifrDisplay" runat="server" scrolling="auto" width="600" height="700"></iframe>
</div>
```

C# code part

```
LinkButton1_click
{
    string pdfUrl = "https://test-folder.com/rxdata//P09/201305240039MA9_000/Data/00000010.pdf";//
    ifrDisplay.Attributes.Add("src", pdfUrl);

}
```

Here the issue is even if the content of the particular pdf changes, still it loads the pdf of older content.
So it is clear this is caching related issue.

Please let me know how to remove the cache due to which still the older content of pdf file is loading.

--Sarthak

Answer (score 0):

To avoid caching you can use some random number in the URL so that browser does not cache the response.

```
string pdfUrl = "https://test-folder.com/rxdata//P09/201305240039MA9_000/Data/00000010.pdf"+DateTime.Now();
```

The second possible option is that who is serving PDF should set the cache to (-1) so that it not get cached in the browser.

Comment: please check the syntax and URL encode the complete URL

Comment: I tried this .. but now the file is not loading now .Checked in debugger the value  of the url is coming as below :                                                                                       https://test-folder.com/rxdata//P09/201305240039MA9_000/Data/00000010.pdf4/11/2022 11:11:51 AM

Comment: https://test-folder.com/rxdata//P09/201305240039MA9_000/Data/00000010.pdf4/11/2022 11:11:51 AM

Comment: This code worked fine..
string pdfUrl = "https://test-folder.com/rxdata//P09/201305240039MA9_000/Data/00000010.pdf"+ "?" + DateTime.Now